# replace DOCVAR values in WORD document from macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

The idea is to create a word document, insert few [FIELDS] and change [FIELD] values so that user doesn't have to manually make the changes. In the macro, i have dialog box that requires user input, then the macro calculates few things, but i am unable to assign the result of the calculation and display it in the text.

If simplified, it looks like this:

```
Sub user_input()
Dim start_date_user As String

start_date_user = InputBox("Enter start date in DD.MM.YYYY format", "Start date", "01.01.2022")

ActiveDocument.Variables("DOC_START").Value = start_date_user 

  
End Sub
```

Then I have the following text in the WORD document (with FIELD defined)

> Bla bla bla {DOCVARIABLE "DOC_START" \ *MERGEFORMAT}  bla bla bla

and I want it to be

> Bla bla bla 01.01.2022 bla bla bla

reflecting the date that user has entered. But it doesn't work, the word document remains intact. Just once it reflected the change, but then it stopped, so not sure what exactly i am doing wrong.

Comment: Fields only update automatically when printing, or switching to Print Preview, and even then only with the related option turned on. It is better to use content controls rather than fields.

Comment: What about using ContentControls? There is e.g. a date-content-control where the user picks the date from a calender s. e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b

Comment: yes, the next step for the user is to print the document with updated values.
Can they see before printing that values been updated?
Can we use vba code to force-update (or even enable update)?

Comment: let me check the content control (thanks for the link), but it is not just about the dates that user enters. There's free-format text as well

Comment: that link was helpful, however i have resolved my issue but just using the field number instead of name
ActiveDocument.Fields(5).Result.Text instead of ActiveDocument.Fields("NAME").Result.Text

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved my issue but just using the field number instead of name
ActiveDocument.Fields(5).Result.Text instead of ActiveDocument.Fields("NAME").Result.Text